# Reuse filters in all routes in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

In my configuration I have the following filters defined in all routes:

```yaml
          filters:
            - name: CacheRequestBody
              args:
                bodyClass: java.lang.String
            - StripPrefix=1
```

I wonder if it's possible to make them "global", so I won't need to define them in each route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters` to apply filters to all routes:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - name: CacheRequestBody
          args:
            bodyClass: java.lang.String
        - StripPrefix=1
```

[Reference documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#default-filters)

Comment: Do you know how do the same for Spring Cloud Gateway MVC?